# recursively split list elements

Tags: r

I cannot find the right incantation of `Reduce`, `Recall`, `lapply` to perform the following task. Consider the following function,

```
bisect.df <- function(d){
  n <- ncol(d)
  if(n%%2) n <- n-1 # drop one col if odd number
  ind <- sample(n)[seq.int(n/2)] # split randomly both parts

  list(first=d[, ind],
       second=d[, -ind])
}
```

given a `data.frame`, it returns a list of two children `data.frames` of equal `ncol` extracted randomly from their parent. I wish to apply this function recursively to the offsprings down to a given level, say 3 generations. I can do it trivially one generation at a time,

```
bisect.list <- function(l){
  unlist(lapply(l, bisect.df), recursive=FALSE)
}
```

but how do I call this recursively, say `N=3` times?

Here's a test sample to play with

```
d <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(16*5), ncol=16))
step1 <- bisect.list(list(d))
step2 <- bisect.list(step1)
step3 <- bisect.list(step2)
str(list(step1, step2, step3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bisect.list <- function(l,n){
  for(i in 1:n) {
    l <- unlist(lapply(l, bisect.df), recursive=FALSE)
  }
  return(l)
}
```

not sure how to do it without a loop...

Comment: I meant to say without `for` loop, to spice things up. But you get +1 because it gets the job done :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive solution: the idea is to add an argument that counts the number of remaining recursive calls. (But it does exactly the same thing as the loop version.)

```
f <- function( d, n=3 ) {
  if( is.data.frame( d ) )
    return( f( list(d), n ) )
  if( n == 0 )
    return( d )
  result <- lapply( d, bisect.df )
  result <- unlist( result, recursive=FALSE )
  result <- f( result, n-1 )
  result
}
d <- as.data.frame( t(1:20) )
f(d)
```

It may be easier to just take the column indices at random 
and build all the sub-data.frames at once.

Comment: good point, in fact it probably makes more sense for my original problem to sample from the first data.frame at each level.